# Combining text within div via css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to combine all the text in one. Below I gave an example of how not right. I would like to make the word "ОН" was common cause with the text below.

I would like to like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3qzv55rbopefet/good.png?dl=0

Roughly speaking I need a div with the attribute "el", to connect with the upper elements. Possible and through js, if there is a solution ... but these attributes are not lost. Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/syxc5yv4/

```
#content-area {
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-column-width: 595px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 99px;
    top: 0px;
}
#content-area > div {
    display: inline;
}
#content-area > div div {
    white-space: normal;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

Comment: not clear what are you asking for?

Comment: are you trying to change the margins and padding?

Comment: For future questions, please post your HTML code as well as the CSS -- the css makes no sense without the html that it should be applied to.

Comment: @starvator http://jsfiddle.net/syxc5yv4/ I need to remove the padding to make it like the picture

Comment: @SashaVasilev I can't see the picture.

Comment: @starvator Danield almost helped me. left to deal with the paragraphs. Perhaps you know a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` to the `#content-area > div div` class

```
    #content-area > div div {
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/syxc5yv4/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but disappeared "text-indent: 30px;"

Comment: Using a <span> would make more sense then.

Comment: @Danield I looked up your fiddle and nothing has changed. indents appeared after the words. But it's not. see picture in the topic. thank you!